# Visual Studio Team Service - Move Artifacts

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I need move/copy artifacts (Example: drop.zip) created in build phase into TFS Team Project folder (Example: $/ProjectA/Zip/). I used copy file but not working. Any ideas?

Regards.

Comment: Why? The entire point of publishing build artifacts is to have a place to put them that's not source control.

Comment: I need to collect the .zip produced by build phase.

Answer (score 0):

Copy files task is used to copy files from a source folder to a target folder such as `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` on the build agent machine using match patterns.

Your requirement is more like **check in build artifacts into source control during the build process**.

> In this case, you could either use the [TFVC Build Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-tfvc-tasks) if you're
>   using TFVC or use the [Git Build Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ioz.vsts-git-build-tasks) to add the remote to the
>   local repository and then use the git commandline tools to commit and
>   push the changes back to the repository.

Note, this is not a suggested behavior, if you insist on this, detail ways please go through the wonderful answer provide by *jessehouwing* in this similar case: [Commit file back to repository from build server in Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645365/commit-file-back-to-repository-from-build-server-in-visual-studio-team-services) and also take a look at the **warning** part.